# Date Hierarchy in Excel

Tags: excel, ssas, visual-studio-2019, cube, sql-server-2019

I'm trying to set up an SSAS cube, and I'm admittedly very new to this exercise. Currently, I have a Date table defined, with hierarchies set up, and which is marked as a date table in my cube:

[image: Date]

I have a relationship set up between this table and one of my fact tables:

[image: Fact Table Relationship]

I'm able to validate that this relationship is correct by using the RELATED function:

[image: Data]

However, when trying to use this in Excel, the relationship doesn't seem to let me properly drill-down:

[image: Excel]

I've tried a whole bunch of things but nothing seems to be working. I feel like this is probably something obvious, but I can't seem to figure it out. Any insights would be appreciated!

Comment: Okay - followup. I have things working - sorta. Rather than trying to tie two separate tables together, if I put the relevant information into the main table (in my above case, FieldLog), I can properly filter/display - IE, in Field Log, if I put a bunch of related columns that reference the info from Date. This seems like a weird solution though, because it means it won't show any drill-down info for dates which don't exist in FieldLog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright - figured it out. Basically - I was misinterpreting how to use the tabular analysis in Excel. Rather than attaching values directly from the fact table, I'm supposed to create measures that aggregate facts, and then attach those measures to dimensions. My above example doesn't really demonstrate this clearly, as the associated table to Date was another dimension table, and not a fact table. Further down in my tree, I do have data points to analyse, and by putting measures on those facts I was properly able to use the hierarchy of dates I had set up.